# Why is an error generated when I declare a nested static Fragment class as private?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-fragments

I created an activity for my Android project and decided to change the access modifier for the  nested Fragment class to "private", I figured that the outer Activity class is the only element of my program that needs to access this Fragment class. When I go to build in eclipse I receive the following error message "This Fragment class should be public ....", why is this error generated?

```
"`private static class PlaceholderFragment extends ListFragment {...."`
```

Comment: Is that an "error" or a "warning"?

Comment: It's an error, fails to build.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the Android framework may need to invoke the no-arg constructor of your Fragment via reflection, which it can't do if the class is private.

Comment: Makes sense.  From the API doc for `Fragment`: "All subclasses of Fragment must include a public empty constructor. The framework will often re-instantiate a fragment class when needed, in particular during state restore, and needs to be able to find this constructor to instantiate it. If the empty constructor is not available, a runtime exception will occur in some cases during state restore."

Comment: Thanks! This makes perfect sense, I figured that there may be something in Framework that needed access to the class, but couldn't put my finger on exactly what it was.